# How to send automatic email through python with data from a pandas DF

Tags: python, email

I have a pandas df with names, emails and others informations.
I want to use the email columns to send automatic emails through python.

So, firstly I import the libraries:

```
import smtplib
import email.message
import pandas as pd
```

After I upload my excel file as as df:

```
df = pd.read_excel('archive.xlsx')
```

thirdly, I created I function called send_email():

```
def send_email(row):
```

Inside this function I do an iteration over the rows of my df:

```
for row in range(0, len(df)):
    office = df['OFFICE'].iloc[row]
    name = df['NAME'].iloc[row]
    email = df['EMAIL'].iloc[row]
```

Then a variable with the message in HTML:

```
text = """
<html>        
    <p>blablbalbalblablablablablablabalbalabalbalbalbalbalbalbalbal</p>
</html>
"""
```

And finally I try to send my email:

```
    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject of my email to {name}" # here should go a different name from my df in each iteraction
    msg['From'] = 'myemail@thing.com'
    msg['To'] = '{email}' # here should go a different email from my df in each iteraction
    password = 'password from google security password stuffs' 
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(text)

    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
    s.starttls()
    # Login Credentials for sending the mail
    s.login(msg['From'], password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string().encode('utf-8'))
return print('Your email has been sent')

send_email()
```

However it happens anything. All the time shows  "TypeError: send_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'" but "row" is defined.
Where precisely am I doing wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition

```
def send_email(row):
```

stipulates exactly one argument, whilst you are calling

```
send_email()
```

that is furnish it with zero arguments. Either rework definition that it does not require any argument or furnish call with suitable argument.